# I'm encountering an issue where my Flutter bloc isn't recognizing the generic type of events I'm trying to receive

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I've properly defined the AuthenticationStatusChanged class right now, but it's not being recognized. I'm using bloc in Flutter. I need to receive events here, but I can't seem to get them. I keep encountering errors, and I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding bloc. Please help.

first this is state code

```
import 'package:login_bloc_example/authentication/bloc/authentication_repository/lib/src/authentication_repository.dart';

sealed class AuthenticationEvent {
  const AuthenticationEvent();
}

final class _AuthenticationStatusChanged extends AuthenticationEvent {
  const _AuthenticationStatusChanged(this.status);

  final AuthenticationStatus status;
}

final class AuthenticationLogoutRequested extends AuthenticationEvent {}
```

and this is bloc code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:login_bloc_example/authentication/bloc/authentication_event.dart';
import 'package:login_bloc_example/authentication/bloc/authentication_repository/lib/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:login_bloc_example/authentication/bloc/authentication_state.dart';
import 'package:login_bloc_example/authentication/bloc/user_repository/lib/user_repository.dart';

class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  AuthenticationBloc({
    required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
    required UserRepository userRepository,
  })  : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        _userRepository = userRepository,
        super(const AuthenticationState.unknown()) {
    on<_AuthenticationStatusChanged>(_onAuthenticationStatusChanged);
    on<AuthenticationLogoutRequested>(_onAuthenticationLogoutRequested);
    _authenticationStatusSubscription = _authenticationRepository.status.listen(
      (status) => add(_AuthenticationStatusChanged(status)),
    );
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  late StreamSubscription<AuthenticationStatus>
      _authenticationStatusSubscription;

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _authenticationStatusSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  Future<void> _onAuthenticationStatusChanged(
    _AuthenticationStatusChanged event,
    Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit,
  ) async {
    switch (event.status) {
      case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
        return emit(const AuthenticationState.unauthenticated());
      case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
        final user = await _tryGetUser();
        return emit(
          user != null
              ? AuthenticationState.authenticated(user)
              : const AuthenticationState.unauthenticated(),
        );
      case AuthenticationStatus.unknown:
        return emit(const AuthenticationState.unknown());
    }
  }

  void _onAuthenticationLogoutRequested(
    AuthenticationLogoutRequested event,
    Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit,
  ) {
    _authenticationRepository.logOut();
  }

  Future<User?> _tryGetUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _userRepository.getUser();
      return user;
    } catch (_) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

please help me.....

I've tried creating another class to solve this problem, but it's not working well either. Please let me know if there's any additional code or parts needed

Answer (score 2):

`_AuthenticationStatusChanged` is a private class. All identifiers that start with an underscore (classes, mixins, class members, etc.) are private, meaning that they are visible only within the library (a library is a single file or a group of files connected with `part` and `part of`).

To make this class public simply remove the underscore at the start of its name.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add:

- part of "bloc_name.dart", to your file with state
- part "state_name.dart", to your file with bloc

This method is used for encapsulating your states